# $ \mu(\{x\in A :\, x-\epsilon\not\in A\})\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set. Consider $$ A_\epsilon=\{x\in \mathbb{R} :\, x-\epsilon\in A\}\, ,$$
I guess it should be true that, for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$,
and $$ \mu( A \setminus A_\epsilon)\rightarrow 0 $$
but I can't prove it... Any hint?

Comment: what's your definition of the set convergence ? write the intersection of $(A_\epsilon)_\epsilon$

Comment: Your $A_{\epsilon}$, defined like this, is a mere translation of $A$

Comment: for marmouset: I have changed my question: now I hope it is clear!
for Vincent: Exactly! Should the result be trivial in such a case?

Comment: Is $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure or some arbitrary Borel measure?

Comment: @saz it is the Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion does not hold true. Consider

$$A := \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [2k,2k+1],$$

then

$$A_{\epsilon} = \epsilon + A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [2k+\epsilon,2k+1+\epsilon]$$

which implies

$$A \backslash A_{\epsilon} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} [2k,2k+\epsilon)$$

for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Consequently,

$$\mu(A \backslash A_{\epsilon}) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \mu([2k,2k+\epsilon)) = \infty$$

for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

Comment: And what if $A$ had finite measure?

Comment: If $A$ has finite measure then the statement is true. It is a consequence of the fact that for every $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, the translates $f_h(y):=f(y-h)$ converge to $f$ in $L^1$ as $h\to 0$. You can prove this by approximation with compactly supported continuous functions. But maybe there is a more direct proof.